# Print button in PrintPreview dialog doesn't work

Tags: mfc

After pressing the print button in **PrintPreview dialog**, nothing comes out. 
I think that **Print dialog** should come out after pressing the print button in **PrintPreview dialog**, but it doesn't.
It just goes back to the main screen.

P.S.

It's not the functions which were already made when I started the project.
I added this functions manually, because I used another view which is derived from **CScrollView**, and the original view (**CMyView**) isn't used.

Here's the code:

```
void SignalView::OnFilePrintPreview()
{
    PRINTDLG printDlg = { 0 };
    printDlg.lStructSize = sizeof(PRINTDLG);
    if (AfxGetApp()->GetPrinterDeviceDefaults(&printDlg))
    {
        if (printDlg.hDevMode)
        {
            DEVMODE *dm = (DEVMODE*)::GlobalLock(printDlg.hDevMode);
            if (dm)
            {
                dm->dmFields |= DM_ORIENTATION;
                dm->dmOrientation = DMORIENT_LANDSCAPE;
                ::GlobalUnlock(printDlg.hDevMode);
            }
        }
    }
    CScrollView::OnFilePrintPreview();
}

BOOL SignalView::OnPreparePrinting(CPrintInfo* pInfo)
{
    __try {
        pInfo->SetMinPage(1);
        pInfo->SetMaxPage(1);
    //  pInfo->m_bPreview = TRUE;
        return DoPreparePrinting(pInfo);
    }__except (GetExceptionCode()==EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION){
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Printer Error!"));
        return FALSE; // Fail!
    }
}

void SignalView::OnBeginPrinting(CDC* pDC, CPrintInfo* pInfo)
{

}

void SignalView::OnEndPrinting(CDC* pDC, CPrintInfo* pInfo)
{

}
```

Is there something that I missed?

Comment: Maybe you don't have `OnFilePrint` in your message map. But it's difficult to say because you haven't shown a lot of code. Changing `CView` to `CScrollView` shouldn't cause any problem here.

Comment: You can also try something: create a test app, with view based on CScrollView, and take from there print and print preview handlers and map them on your application, with appropriate code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments. I put OnFilePrint message map, which is ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_PRINT, &CScrollView::OnFilePrint), and it now functions really well.